# Int ++ is adding 4 instead of 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, integer

I'm trying to add the value 1 to an int each time I press a button, but when I do it adds 4.

```
-(IBAction)donePressed {


timesPressed ++;

thirdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Times done: %i", timesPressed];

}
```

When I do this, it prints out 4,8,12,16 instead of 1,2,3,4

Thanks

Comment: Can you put an NSLog to make sure it's being called only once? Also, can you show us where you are declaring your int?

Comment: I'll check the NSLog in a sec, but all I'm doing is in .h int *timesPressed; and in .m timesPressed = 0; in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Obviously timesPressed is a pointer type! Now, how did you get the compiler to NOT warn you about the printf format / argument incompatibilities? I'm sure there are some warnings you could switch on so this wouldn't happen again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to your last comment above, timesPressed is defined as `int *timesPressed;`

This is incorrect, you want to define it as `int timesPressed;`

Doing `+` on a pointer type multiplies the addition by the size of the type, read up on pointers and pointer arithmetic if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

In the header file, it should not be `int *timesPressed`. It should be `int timesPressed;`

Answer (score -2):

have you tried using %d instead of %i ?

Comment: %d and %i are identical, both mean "signed int"